# Jquery doesn't execute function choose language webapp

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let me explain my problem:

Actually I don't know how make it so, I accept suggestions too. I'm trying to make to the user choose the default language  on the first step in my webbapp by `$(document).ready`. Then, adter make the choice, I send cookies with lan=es (spanish) or lan=en (english) to make possible analyze it before load all the pages and then display a language or the other.

So, making this plan, I tried to do this:

***STYLE:***

```
#choose-language-wrapper{ /* contenedor grande para eleccion de idioma */
    display: none;
    background-color: black;
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 95%;
    height: 95vh;
    z-index: 999;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 2%;
    top: 2%;
}
    #choose-language-content{
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 80%;
        margin-top: 10%;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
    }
        #language-question h1{ /* pregunta en castellano */
            font-size: 3em;
            font-weight: bolder;
        }
        #language-question h3{/* pregunta en ingles */
            font-size: 2.5em;
            margin-top: 2%;
        }
    #language-ask-javascript{
        margin-top: 20%;
    }
        #language-ask-javascript button{ /* caracteristicas del button de eleccion de idioma */
            width: 300px;
            height: 100px;
            font-size: 3em;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            background-color: white;
            font-weight: 900;
            color: black;
            border: solid 3px white;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
            -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
            transition: all 0.5s ease;
        }
        #language-ask-javascript button:hover{/* efectos del button :hover */
            cursor: pointer;
            color: white;
            background-color: black;
        }
```

***HTML***

```
<div id="choose-language-wrapper">
        <div id="choose-language-content">
            <div id="language-question">
                <h1>¿Qué idioma quieres como predefinido?</h1>
                <h3>¿What language do you want as default?</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="language-ask-javascript">
                    <button id="spanish">Español</button >
                    <button  id="english">English</button >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

***JAVASCRIPT***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#choose-language-wrapper').fadeIn('slow');
});

var a = function(){
    $('#spanishChoice').click(function(){
    document.cookie = "lan=es";

    $('#choose-language-wrapper').fadeOut();
    }
)};

var b = function(){
    $('#englishChoice').click(function(){
    document.cookie = "lan=en"

    $('#choose-language-wrapper').fadeOut();
    }
)};
```

I also tried to dont declare the "var 'x' = function..." and just do

```
$('#englishChoice').click(function(){
        document.cookie = "lan=en"
        $('#choose-language-wrapper').fadeOut();
```

But it didn't work anyway so, what I should do?
There is a better way to do what iIwant? I read that the lan navigator not always work successfully!

Comment: For a start you don't have an element with an id of `englishChoice`. You have one called `english`  tho. See also `spanishChoice` and `spanish`.

Comment: **FIXED** Had to rewrite the div#id and change a JS thing.
Thanks!